# Less variables: @@var

Tags: css, variables, less

Can someone please explain this variable example on the Less.org documentation:

> It is also possible to define variables with a variable name:

```
@fnord: "I am fnord.";
@var: 'fnord';
content: @@var;
```

> Which compiles to:

```
content: "I am fnord.";
```

The part that confuses me is the double @.

Thanks.

Comment: Which part are you confused about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This statement explain itself

```
It is also possible to define variables with a variable name:
```

So: `content: @@var;` is actually  `content: @fnord;` which is `content: "I am fnord.";`

**NOTE:** *You can consider `@@` as a pointer notation `@` as a variable*

Comment: I just noticed the different quotes in
`@fnord` and
`@var`, but aren't both supposed to be strings? Actually, that helps me understand perfectly:

`@@var` is actually `@ + the string "fnord"`, is that right?

Answer (score 2):

The `@var` part of `content: @@var` evaluates to the value of the `@var` variable which is `fnord`, which makes it `content: @fnord`.

The `@fnord` part in turn is evaluated as the value of the variable `@fnord` which is `"I am fnord."` making it `content: "I am fnord."`'

Answer (score 0):

Very much like [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). Dynamic variables were you might not know the name of the variable or its value until you create it.  I find the PHP examples very helpful to explain what is happening.

Let say you have a monster site and you do not know what the variable you will need.  You don't want to include them all so at runtime you can produce the dynamic variable.

Without loops and the power you get from PHP, not sure the @@ is as helpful for the normal average user.